# How do you restrict road access by time in ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, time, road, parameters

I was wondering if there's a way to restrict road access based on time of day (i.e., create a time restricted road).
I'm familiar with restricting roads based on vehicle weight/height, but time restriction is a little different-- there's no time unit in ArcGIS (or at least I'm not aware of it).

I was thinking of using python to script the restrictions. I'd create 2 new fields (double) in the road network attribute table, 1 for when the time restriction starts and 1 for when it ends (restrict_tstart, restrict_tend).
For example if the road is restricted between 10am - 2:30pm, I would put 10 in restrict_tstart and 14.5 in restrict_tend.
Then I'd write a python code that returns True when the real time falls between restrict_start and restrict_tend.

Does that work? I'm not even sure where to put that script in ArcMap.

Suggestions, anyone?

Comment: Impedance must be set to use TravelTime (Minutes) http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0047000001s6000000

Comment: I'm not really sure if this is what I'm looking for.. could you please explain more? I would like to know how to restrict road access from 2pm to 4pm for example. Thanks.